# Android ImageView set non int ID

Tags: android

Is it possible to set ImageViews id with a String?

I'm adding ImageViews programmatically and i want to set the ID the something like "IMG12a"

```
    ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
    params.leftMargin = X;
    params.topMargin = Y;
    image.setLayoutParams(params);
    image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    image.setImageResource(IMG);
    image.setId(?????);
    theLayout.addView(image);
```

Comment: `id` is used to find the view declared in a view hierarchy. If you want a reference to the views to access them programatically, follow the instructions provided by Ryan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with setId,

you should use `setTag(Object tag)` (you can use a string and you don't need to convert it to an Object).

and use `View.findViewWithTag(Object tag)` in order to get the View and modify it.

if you need the get a tag - use `getTag()`. and `getTag().toString()` in order to get it as a string.

Answer (score 3):

No, but you could use `setTag (int key, Object tag)` or `setTag (Object tag)` instead.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(int, java.lang.Object)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29)
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28java.lang.Object%29)

and get the tag with `getTag (int key)` or `getTag ()`, respectively.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag%28int%29)
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag%28%29)

You'll then need to cast the returned `Object` to a `String`.